# renaming repository folder

Tags: version-control, bazaar

When I rename my repository folder in Nautilus, Bazaar can't open it any longer. In All Commands, there is a renames command, but it's not what I want. Bazaar claims to have the best renaming, so in the other VCSs, is everything unrenameable? What's going on? How do I rename my repository folder?

Comment: Is it your question? https://answers.launchpad.net/bzr-explorer/+question/116976

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on more info from https://answers.launchpad.net/bzr-explorer/+question/116976 you have colocated workspace and you want to rename it. Because colocated workspace uses trick with lightweight checkouts and the latter using absolute path to point on the real branch inside colocated workspace, you have to execute `bzr colo-fixup` command after rename of colocated workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Use Bazaar's rename option.

Comment: I got a "bzr: ERROR: iloved bg is not in the same branch as ilovedbzrgit" for "bzr mv ilovedbzrgit 'iloved bg'".

Comment: I got a "bzr: ERROR: Could not rename ilovedbzrgit => ilovedbg: ilovedbzrgit is not versioned." for "bzr mv ilovedbzrgit ilovedb".